# More efficient webgl animated color interpolation?

Tags: javascript, webgl, shaders

The code below creates an animated, four-cornered gradient with vertex and fragment shaders in WebGl. When I run it in the browser, the fans on my MacBookPro (2.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 with Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB) sound like the laptop is preparing for takeoff. I've included screenshots from the Activity Monitor below. I am hesitant to put this code on the web for others. Is there something I could do to make it more efficient?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>webgl-test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="glCanvas" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
    var time0 = new Date().getTime();
    var speed = 3;  // lower is faster

    const verts = [
        -1, -1,
        1, -1,
        1, 1,
        -1, 1
    ];

    const corners = [
        0, 1,
        2, 0,
        2, 3
    ];

    // vertex shader to establish 2x2 texture so that each pixel is interpolated across four colors
    // instead of over two triangles
    const vs = `
        attribute vec2 verts;
        varying vec2 coord2D;
        
        void main() {
            coord2D = verts * 0.5 + 0.5; // convert to quad space 0,0 <=> 1, 1
            gl_Position = vec4(verts, 1, 1); 
        }
    `;

    // hard coding the colors to be more efficient
    const fs = `
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec2 coord2D;
        uniform float uTime;

        vec3 tl0 = vec3(0.93725,0.16471,0.75686);   // rose
        vec3 tl1 = vec3(1.0,0.611765,0.0);          // saffron

        vec3 tr0 = vec3(0.11765,0.69804,1.0);       // ocean
        vec3 tr1 = vec3(0.76471,0.90196,0.54510);   // lime

    
        vec3 bl0 = vec3(0.26275,0.33333,0.78431);   // sapphire
        vec3 bl1 = vec3(0.81176,0.60392,0.67843);   // lavender

        // vec3 br0 = vec3(1.0,0.78039,0.0);           // sun
        vec3 br0 = vec3(1.0,0.611765,0.0);          // saffron
        vec3 br1 = vec3(1.0,0.67451,0.43137);       // turmeric


        void main() {
            float pct = abs(sin(uTime));

            vec4 pixel = vec4(vec3(mix(
                        mix(mix(bl0, br0, coord2D.x), mix(bl1, br1, coord2D.x), pct),
                        mix(mix(tl0, tr0, coord2D.x), mix(tl1, tr1, coord2D.x), pct),
                        coord2D.y
                    )), 1);

            gl_FragColor = pixel;
        }
    `;

    // create and compile the shaders
    function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
        const shader = gl.createShader(type);

        //send source to the shader object
        gl.shaderSource(shader, source);

        //compile the shader program
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        // check
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.log('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            gl.deleteShader(shader);
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    // initialize shader program and attach the shaders
    function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
        const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
        const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);
        const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        // check
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            console.log('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
            return null;
        }

        return shaderProgram;
    }

    function main() {
        const canvas = document.querySelector("#glCanvas");
        const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
        var loc;

        if (canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
            [canvas.width, canvas.height] = [innerWidth, innerHeight];
            gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        const program = initShaderProgram(gl, vs, fs);

        // create buffers
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(corners), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);   

        // setup attribute
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(loc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "verts"));
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 
        
        // setup uniform
        const timeLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uTime');

        // draw loop
        function draw() {
            let newTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000 - time0 /1000;
            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

            gl.useProgram(program);
            gl.uniform1f(timeLoc, newTime/speed);
            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); 
        }

        function render(now) {
            draw();
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(render);

    } 

    main();
</script>
</html>
```

[image: Activity Monitor when running in Firefox]

[image: Activity Monitor when running in Chrome]

Comment: Your title, stating the concerns you have about your code, applies to tooany questions on this site. Please consider making it more specific, simply stating what your code does would suffice.